# Spring JDBC - .queryForObject() returns too many results?

Tags: java, spring, jdbc

I have this SQL statement:

```
return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("SELECT * FROM materials WHERE title = ?", new MaterialMapper(), title);
```

And since I'm using `.queryForObject` I'm expecting to get just one or no results back. Instead I'm getting more than 1 result back which throws the `IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException`.

Comment: Yes, but shouldn't .queryForObject only return one of these objects?

Comment: I see, I will try it out.

Comment: Yeah that worked, thanks!

Comment: I rolled back your edit, answer should be posted in the answer section. Which I did now :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method [`queryForObject(sql, rowMapper, args)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.5.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#queryForObject-java.lang.String-org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper-java.lang.Object...-) (and all the overload) declare explicitely to throw an [`IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.5.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException.html) if the query returns more than 1 row, or does not return anything:

> Throws: `IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException` - if the query does not return exactly one row

In your case, since the query `SELECT * FROM materials WHERE title = ?` can return more than 1 row, you have two choices:

- Either use the [`query(sql, rowMapper, args)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.5.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#query-java.lang.String-org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper-java.lang.Object...-) method instead, which returns a `List` of elements and not just a single row. You can then use it to retrieve only the first element (if the list isn't empty).
- Adjust your query so that it returns a single row by limiting the result.

Answer (score 0):

In case the query is meant to return just one row you can also use `WHERE ROWNUM = 1` clause.

That would save you from the exception - but you need to be cautious:

- the result can be non-deterministic,
- it can hide the problem in your app
- and let the data corruption go unnoticed.